# Dynamic change texrview value in group of LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am creating LinearLayout in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="398dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.41" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and the linear layout item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#d9dbd6">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
     android:layout_margin="5dp"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/courseheader"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="اسم المساق "
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_id"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
       android:text="رقم المساق: ...."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teachername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="اسم المحاضر : ...."
         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" 
         android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/days"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="الايام : ...." 
         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
         android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="الوقت: .... "
         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"  
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hole"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="القاعة : .... "
         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
         android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in java i have outer array have the data i want to add in the textview

```
    for (int i=0;i<outer.size();i++){
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(CopyOfstudanttable.this).inflate(R.layout.studanttableitem,null);
                        ll.addView(view);

        }
```

when i want to cheng value only the first liner chang

```
            for (int i=0;i<outer.size();i++){


                 coNa =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.course_name);
                 coId =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.course_id);
                 coNa.setText(""+outer.get(0).get(0));
                 coId.setText("رقم المساق :- "+outer.get(0).get(1));

    }
```

How can I change all linear add by loop?